# Using IF with JOIN in SELECT mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get data and join the table with other IF match certain attribute in base table. Following code may explain what I am trying to do:

```
SELECT * FROM Base_Table 
LEFT JOIN 
IF(Base_Table.Class = "A", 
    Type ON Type.Id = Base_Table.Type_Id, 
    Box_Type ON Box_Type.Id = Base_Table.Type_Id)
WHERE Base_Table.Id = 4;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same question as your but I found solution by using `UNION`; IF is for select filed not for table. I will suggest you to use `UNION` like in example below:

```
SELECT * FROM Base_Table 
LEFT JOIN Type ON Type.Id = Base_Table.Type_Id
WHERE Base_Table.Id = 4

UNION

SELECT * FROM Base_Table  
LEFT JOIN Box_Type ON Box_Type.Id = Base_Table.Type_Id
WHERE Base_Table.Id = 4;
```

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: This works fine if the tables `Type` and `Box_Type` have the same number of columns and in the same order (as to their meaning). Otherwise, you may need to name the columns from those tables explicitly, instead of using `*`